# Pass reference as default for specific function JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this:

```
function helperFunction (text, setState) {
    setState({
        value: "some value",
        text: text
    });
    return "result";
}

function mainFunction (state, setState) {
    switch (state.value) {
        case "" : return helperFunction("empty string", setState);
        case "aaa" : return helperFunction("the string is aaa", setState);
        case "bbb" : return helperFunction("the string is bbb", setState); 
        case ...
        default ...
    }
}
```

These functions are in external file so I have to pass setState reference in order to be able to update the state (via useReducer/useState Hooks).

`helperFunction` is a helper function, and I want to optimize this code and get rid of necessity of passing `setState` reference to it **every time/case**, which is always the same for the `mainFunction`.

How do I can pass setState to `helperFunction` as a default for the `mainFunction`?

To be clear

I want:

```
case "aaa" : return helperFunction("the string is aaa");
```

instead of:

```
case "aaa" : return helperFunction("the string is aaa", setState);
```

What is the "best practices" for this case?

PS: `helper` is a universal, and I need to be able to change its defaults depending on function that is running it.

Update: some answers suggest to put it inside the mainFunction - I can't do this, helper is a universal function, any function should be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `helperFunction` into `mainFunction`:

```js
function mainFunction (state, setState) {
    function helperFunction (text) {
        setState({
            value: "some value",
            text: text
        });
        return "result";
    }

    switch (state.value) {
        case "" : return helperFunction("empty string");
        case "aaa" : return helperFunction("the string is aaa");
        case "bbb" : return helperFunction("the string is bbb"; 
        case ...
        default ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

How about declare a wrapper function of `helperFunction`?

```
function helperFunction (text, setState) {
    setState({
        value: "some value",
        text: text
    });
    return "result";
}

function mainFunction (state, setState) {
    function helperFunctionWrapper(text) {
        return helperFunction(text, setState);
    }

    switch (state.value) {
        case "" : return helperFunctionWrapper("empty string");
        case "aaa" : return helperFunctionWrapper("the string is aaa");
        case "bbb" : return helperFunctionWrapper("the string is bbb"); 
        case ...
        default ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this one should work too, but only if both functions are to be kept together.

Comment: Obvious, but I, as I mentioned, I can't  do this - helper is a **universal function**, any function should be able run it

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass access to `this` to your helper function instead of setstate. Although by looking at you code i can't assess whether your helper function is common to many components or not. Depending upon that you might need to pass `this` to your mainFunction as well (to be accessed by helper function).